# Get Amount of Free Space Available -GDI+ Generic Exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gdi+, system.io.file

GDI+ is throwing `Generic Exception` when i try to Save Bitmaps to a drive with low disk space.

So im trying to do this to check and see if at-least 10MB is available on the Drive.

```
DriveInfo[] oDrvs = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (var Drv in oDrvs) {
        if (Drv.IsReady) {
            Console.WriteLine(Drv.Name + " " + Drv.AvailableFreeSpace.ToString);
        }
}
```

But what i have is a Path not a drive letter,i can do something like

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(path);    
string drive = Path.GetPathRoot(f.FullName);
```

But i dont know how i can use `drive` as a parameter for the above code.Please advice.

Comment: @HansPassant I have specified the same thing in my question..But i dont know how to give a string `drive` parameter to  the first method..it seems to use an array of the type `DriveInfo[] oDrvs` I just need a method to give `drive` from this as parameter  `string drive = Path.GetPathRoot(f.FullName);`  and get the free space.

Comment: Don't use GetDrives(), pass *path* to the DriveInfo constructor.  A path name instead of a letter is fine, it already calls Path.GetPathRoot().  Be prepared to catch an exception, this cannot work on UNC paths.

Comment: @HansPassant Hope this method will be fine `Boolean getdrivespace(string filepath)
        {
            try
            {
                DriveInfo dinfo = new DriveInfo(filepath);
                if (dinfo.AvailableFreeSpace < 10485760)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }`